# How to sum the entered values with user input

Tags: python, loops, sum

First, the program asks the user the amount of numbers to sum.(n)
Then the user enters values in amount(n), lastly the entered values gets summed and should be printed out.
I written the base of the code, but can't find how I can sum all the entered values into one.

Input: 5, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10
Output: 30

Here is my code:

```py
n = int(input("Amount of numbers to sum: "))
for i in range (0,n):
  s = float(input("Enter number: "))
```

Would appreciate some recommendations regarding this.

Comment: Put `s=0` before the loop, and `s=s+float...` in the loop. And `print(s)` after the loop.

Comment: `s = sum(float(input("Enter number: ")) for _ in range(n))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new variable outside the loop and set its value to 0. Inside teh for loop, add the input number to the variable.

```py
final_sum = 0

for i in range (0,n):
  s = float(input("Enter number: "))
  final_sum = final_sum + s    #or use final_sum += s

print(final_sum)
```